# Android - SMS sent intent not received 100% of time

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-pendingintent

I'm sending more than 400 sms messages a day, but only for around 95% of them i receive the sms sent intent into the broadcast receiver. The messages are sent at 5 seconds interval.

```
ArrayList<String> partsArray = SmsManager.getDefault().divideMessage(this.message);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents = new ArrayList<>(partsArray.size());
ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredPendingIntents = new ArrayList<>(partsArray.size());
      .....

for (int i = 0; i < partsArray.size(); i++) {
        sentIntent = new Intent("SMS_SENT_2");
        deliveredIntent = new Intent(C.SMS_DELIVERED);
        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, deliveredIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        sentPendingIntents.add(sentPI);
        deliveredPendingIntents.add(deliveredPI);
}

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,partsArray, sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);
```

and the broadcast receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="._broadcastReceivers.SMSSentBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="SMS_SENT_2" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I know for a fact that for some of the messages the broadcast receiver didn't get the intent, but the sms was actually sent.

How can i reliably determine whether an sms "left the phone" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` you should ensure that the `PendingIntent`s are unique. The easiest way to do that is to use explicit `Intent` instead of implicit `Intent` and make sure that the ACTION in each `Intent` is unique. Here's an example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < partsArray.size(); i++) {
    sentIntent = new Intent(this, _broadcastReceivers.SMSSentBroadcastReceiver.class);
    sentIntent.setAction("SMS_SENT_2" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    deliveredIntent = new Intent(this, DeliveryReceiver.class);
    deliveredIntent.setAction(C.SMS_DELIVERED + System.currentTimeMillis());
    sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sentIntent, 0);
    deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, deliveredIntent, 0);

    sentPendingIntents.add(sentPI);
    deliveredPendingIntents.add(deliveredPI);
}
```

I've ensured that the ACTION is unique by appending the current timestamp to each ACTION.

You can now remove the `<intent-filter>` from the manifest definition for the `BroadcastReceiver` as you don't need it anymore (you are using explicit `Intent`). Make sure, however, that you add `android:exported="true"` to the manifest definition for the `BroadcastReceiver` because it will not be exported unless you either have an `<intent-filter>` or specifically declare that it is exported.